# Monitoring docker container from docker-java API

Tags: java, docker, monitoring

I'm starting with docker-java API. I read some examples from the test repositoty.
I have generated a container from java api. afterwards, I want to monitor this container. In other words, translate `docker stats myContainer` in Java API.

When I make: `docker stats container1`  from shell I got this result:

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT    MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
container1          0.00%               92 KiB / 995.9 MiB   0.01%               648 B / 648 B       0 B / 0 B           1
```

However, when I try to retreive these results from docker-Java API like this:

```
    List<Container> containers = dockerClient.listContainersCmd().exec();
    for(Container container: containers){
        InspectContainerResponse response= dockerClient.inspectContainerCmd(container.getId()).exec();
        System.out.println(response.getHostConfig());
    }
```

I Obtain:

> com.github.dockerjava.api.model.HostConfig@1992eaf4[binds=,blkioWeight=0,blkioWeightDevice=,blkioDeviceReadBps=,blkioDeviceReadIOps=,blkioDeviceWriteBps=,blkioDeviceWriteIOps=,memorySwappiness=-1,capAdd=,capDrop=,containerIDFile=,**cpuPeriod**=0,**cpuShares**=0,**cpuQuota**=0,**cpusetC**pus=,cpusetMems=,devices={},dns={},dnsSearch={},extraHosts=,links=,logConfig=com.github.dockerjava.api.model.LogConfig@f74e835,lxcConf=,**memory**=0,**memorySwap**=0,**memoryReservation**=0,kernelMemory=0,networkMode=default,oomKillDisable=false,oomScoreAdj=false,portBindings={80/tcp=[Lcom.github.dockerjava.api.model.Ports$Binding;@21d8bcbe},privileged=false,publishAllPorts=false,readonlyRootfs=false,restartPolicy=no,ulimits=,volumesFrom=,pidMode=,securityOpts=,cgroupParent=,volumeDriver=,shmSize=67108864]

All attributes are 0 !!! some one can explain for me how can I retreive the same result as `docker stats myContainer` ?

Comment: You want to monitor the container from inside the container?

Comment: @R0MANARMY Yes. Monitor what the application inside the container consumes